# Lower bound to expectation expression

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose I have a random variable $x$ and $E[x] =y$. Moreover $E[x^2] \leq M$. I have $E[\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + c}}y]$ where $c$ is some positive constant. My question is can be show a (tight) lower bound to the above exression?

Comment: Unless you condition a random variable on something, the expected value is a deterministic quantity, so you can't have $E[y]=x$.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. I meant $E[x] = y$